# Not able to return output only only once in setInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a spaceship shooter game. In it, when the bullet hits moving bar it should return "Hit" in the console.

I have used setInterval method and I am getting the position of bullet and bar and comparing them whenever the bullet hits the bar. But since I am using setInterval it returns "Hit" multiple times. If I write the condition outside setInterval it does not work properly.

I want it to return "Hit" only once whenever the bullet hits the bar.

Spaceship moves with arrow keys and fires with space.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var keyLeft = 37,
    keyRight = 39,
    keyDown = 40,
    keyTop = 38,
    keySpace = 32;
  var spaceship = $("#spaceship");
  var bullet = $("#bullet");
  var speed = 5;
  var bar = $('#bar');
  var bulletPosTop;
  var win_Ht = $(window).height();
  var win_calc = win_Ht - 70;
  var barPos, barPosBottom;

  spaceship.css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "left": 10
  });
  bullet.css({
    "display": "none",
    "position": "absolute"
  });

  bar.css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": 0,
    "right": 10
  });

  direction = {
    left: false,
    right: false,
    top: false,
    down: false
  }
  bulletSpeed = 1;
  bulletState = {
    state: "available"
  }

  //When Key is Pressed
  $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pressedKey = e.keyCode;
    if (pressedKey == keyLeft) {
      direction.left = true;
    }
    if (pressedKey == keyRight) {
      direction.right = true;
    }
    if (pressedKey == keyTop) {
      direction.top = true;
    }
    if (pressedKey == keyDown) {
      direction.down = true;
    }
    if (pressedKey == keySpace && bulletState.state === "available") {
      bulletState.state = "fire";
    }
  });

  //When key is released
  $(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var releaseKey = e.keyCode;
    if (releaseKey == keyLeft) {
      direction.left = false;
    }
    if (releaseKey == keyRight) {
      direction.right = false;
    }
    if (releaseKey == keyTop) {
      direction.top = false;
    }
    if (releaseKey == keyDown) {
      direction.down = false;
    }
  });


  //Move function for Spaceship and Bullet
  function move() {
    if (direction.left) {
      spaceship.css(
        'left', (spaceship.position().left - speed) + "px"
      );
    }
    if (direction.right) {
      spaceship.css(
        'left', (spaceship.position().left + speed) + "px"
      );
    }
    if (direction.top) {
      spaceship.css(
        'top', (spaceship.position().top - speed) + "px"
      );
    }
    if (direction.down) {
      spaceship.css(
        'top', (spaceship.position().top + speed) + "px"
      );
    }
    if (bulletState.state == "fire") {
      bulletState.state = "unavailable";
      bullet.css({
        "display": "block",
        "left": spaceship.position().left + 50 + "px",
        "top": spaceship.position().top + 50 + "px",
      }).animate({
        "left": "1500"
      }, 1000 / bulletSpeed, function() {
        bullet.css({
          "display": "none",
        })
        bulletState.state = "available";
      });

      //Check Bullet Position with Bar Position
      setInterval(function() {
        bulletPosTop = bullet.css("top").replace("px", "");
        barPos = bar.position().top;
        barPosBottom = bar.position().top + 70;
        if ((bulletPosTop >= barPos) && (bulletPosTop <= barPosBottom)) {
          console.log("Hit");
        }
      }, 100);

    }

  }

  const obstacleMove = () => {
    if (bar.position().top == 0) {
      bar.animate({
        "top": win_calc
      }, 1000);
    } else if (bar.position().top == win_calc) {
      bar.animate({
        "top": 0
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  setInterval(obstacleMove, 1000);

  setInterval(function() {
    move();
  }, 10);


});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#spaceship {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url('http://www.pngmart.com/files/3/Spaceship-PNG-File.png');
  background-size: contain;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#bullet {
  width: 60px;
}

#bar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="spaceship">SpaceShip</div>
<div id="bullet">---></div>
<div id="bar"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Please help.

Comment: so you can add a class to spaceship when ever it hit the bar and return false if the class exist

Comment: I need to return "hit" once only because I want to keep a score counter with it that increments only once when "hit". There would be no point of adding a class if it would keep on adding, again and again, due to setInterval and score counter will also keep on incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible solutions to handle that issue. One of them is to simply move your bullet outside of the playable screen when it hits your target:

```
if ((bulletPosTop >= barPos) && (bulletPosTop <= barPosBottom)) {
    console.log("Hit");
    // Move outside of playable screen.
    bullet.css({
        "top":"-100px",
    });
}
```

Open the below snippet to test it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var keyLeft = 37,
    keyRight = 39,
    keyDown = 40,
    keyTop = 38,
    keySpace = 32;
  var spaceship = $("#spaceship");
  var bullet = $("#bullet");
  var speed = 5;
  var bar = $('#bar');
  var bulletPosTop;
  var win_Ht = $(window).height();
  var win_calc = win_Ht - 70;
  var barPos, barPosBottom;

  spaceship.css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "left": 10
  });
  bullet.css({
    "display": "none",
    "position": "absolute"
  });

  bar.css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": 0,
    "right": 10
  });

  direction = {
    left: false,
    right: false,
    top: false,
    down: false
  }
  bulletSpeed = 1;
  bulletState = {
    state: "available"
  }

  //When Key is Pressed
  $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pressedKey = e.keyCode;
    if (pressedKey == keyLeft) {
      direction.left = true;
    }
    if (pressedKey == keyRight) {
      direction.right = true;
    }
    if (pressedKey == keyTop) {
      direction.top = true;
    }
    if (pressedKey == keyDown) {
      direction.down = true;
    }
    if (pressedKey == keySpace && bulletState.state === "available") {
      bulletState.state = "fire";
    }
  });

  //When key is released
  $(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var releaseKey = e.keyCode;
    if (releaseKey == keyLeft) {
      direction.left = false;
    }
    if (releaseKey == keyRight) {
      direction.right = false;
    }
    if (releaseKey == keyTop) {
      direction.top = false;
    }
    if (releaseKey == keyDown) {
      direction.down = false;
    }
  });


  //Move function for Spaceship and Bullet
  function move() {
    if (direction.left) {
      spaceship.css(
        'left', (spaceship.position().left - speed) + "px"
      );
    }
    if (direction.right) {
      spaceship.css(
        'left', (spaceship.position().left + speed) + "px"
      );
    }
    if (direction.top) {
      spaceship.css(
        'top', (spaceship.position().top - speed) + "px"
      );
    }
    if (direction.down) {
      spaceship.css(
        'top', (spaceship.position().top + speed) + "px"
      );
    }
    if (bulletState.state == "fire") {
      bulletState.state = "unavailable";
      bullet.css({
        "display": "block",
        "left": spaceship.position().left + 50 + "px",
        "top": spaceship.position().top + 50 + "px",
      }).animate({
        "left": "1500"
      }, 1000 / bulletSpeed, function() {
        bullet.css({
          "display": "none",
        })
        bulletState.state = "available";
      });

      //Check Bullet Position with Bar Position
      setInterval(function() {
        bulletPosTop = bullet.css("top").replace("px", "");
        barPos = bar.position().top;
        barPosBottom = bar.position().top + 70;
        if ((bulletPosTop >= barPos) && (bulletPosTop <= barPosBottom)) {
          console.log("Hit");
          // Move outside of playable screen.
          bullet.css({
            "top":"-100px",
          });
        }
      }, 100);

    }

  }

  const obstacleMove = () => {
    if (bar.position().top == 0) {
      bar.animate({
        "top": win_calc
      }, 1000);
    } else if (bar.position().top == win_calc) {
      bar.animate({
        "top": 0
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  setInterval(obstacleMove, 1000);

  setInterval(function() {
    move();
  }, 10);


});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#spaceship {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url('http://www.pngmart.com/files/3/Spaceship-PNG-File.png');
  background-size: contain;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#bullet {
  width: 60px;
}

#bar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="spaceship">SpaceShip</div>
<div id="bullet">---></div>
<div id="bar"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However, you have other issues that I don't resolve because there are not answers of your question.

But you should also check vertical positions of the bullet and the target for testing the collision between both. Currently,`Hit` is logged **just** when your bullet's y-position is between the top and bottom borders of your target. You also need to check if the bullet's x-position is between the left and right borders of your target.